# Runtime Error: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Could not find metadata file. [[{{node LoadDataset/_1}}]] [Op:DatasetFromGraph]

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

As [in the tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/simulations), trying to execute `tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn, client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(0.02))` but on orchestrator (server) with data saved on edge node (client) using `tf.data.experimental.load()` method:

```
@tff.tf_computation
def make_data():
    element_spec = collections.OrderedDict([('x', tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 784), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)),
             ('y', tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))])
    data = tf.data.experimental.load('./train_data', element_spec = element_spec)
    return data
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1767] OP_REQUIRES failed at dataset_ops.cc:175 : Not found: Could not find metadata file.
         [[{{node LoadDataset/_1}}]]
```

TF data was saved using `tf.data.experimental.save(train_data[0], './train_data')` method. The implementation works when executed locally: `tff.backends.native.set_local_execution_context()`

python - 3.7

libraries versions:

tensorflow - 2.5.2

tensorflow-estimator - 2.5.0

tensorflow-federated - 0.19.0

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Hi Alisher, I tried `train_data = [make_data()]` in that tutorial and it seems to work. Could you add more detail how you generated train_data?

Comment: Hi Wennan Zhu, thanks for quick response. The logic to save data is as follows:


source, _ = tff.simulation.datasets.emnist.load_data()
def map_fn(example):
  return collections.OrderedDict(
      x=tf.reshape(example['pixels'], [-1, 784]), y=example['label'])
def client_data(n):
  ds = source.create_tf_dataset_for_client(source.client_ids[n])
  return ds.repeat(10).batch(20).map(map_fn)
train_data = [client_data(n) for n in range(10)]

tf.data.experimental.save(train_data[0], './train_data')

Comment: Hi Alisher, seems your code to generate data is almost the same as in the tutorial? I tried your code together with your make_data() function, and replaced `state, metrics = trainer.next(state, train_data)` with `state, metrics = trainer.next(state, [make_data()])`. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you decorate a Python function with `@tff.tf_computation` it will serialize the contents as a `tf.Graph` to be reused later. Frankly, I do not know how I/O like the experimental tf.data load logic interacts with it.

The recommended pattern would be to avoid that, and instead load the data in Python at the level where you are creating TFF computations, and pass the loaded dataset as an input to your `tff.tf_computation` or `tff.federated_computation`, with matching type signature (`tff.types.SequenceType`).